# Amazon ECS - add --shm-size to Docker run

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I need to add the shm-size option to the docker run command for the containers run in my cluster on ECS.

I cannot see any documented or obvious way to do that in ECS console.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like currently it's not possible, please check https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/502